# How to delete all files in a folder without deleting specific extensions

Tags: directory

I am asking this question for a friend and possibly for me to in the future. He has his phone data backed up and wanted to delete everything in the backup folder except for certain file extensions like .jpg, .png, .mp4, etc. Is there a way to filter these extensions from being deleted? And if yes, how can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible, I found a link [here](https://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch001760.htm) that details how to do it via various scripting languages on different operating systems.

For windows in CMD shell this is what the website suggests:

```
for /f %F in ('dir /b /a-d ^| findstr /vile ".tiff .jpg"') do del "%F"
```

"In the example above, the command is deleting all files in the current directory, except files with the file extension .tiff and .jpg."(Computer Hope)

If you wanted to do this in a batch file, you must change %F to %%F.

So with the above examples you might want to do something like this in a batch file:

```
for /f %%F in ('dir /b /a-d ^| findstr /vile ".png .jpg .mp4"') do del "%%F"
```

It should go without saying that you should test this in a safe way, like copying a small group of folders and running the batch file against it, verifying that it worked that way you intended. Files deleted in this way cannot be recovered, save for with recovery tools.

My honest opinion here is that despite how tedious it may be, manually going through the directories is the most foolproof way to ensure you save all the data you want.

Comment: I tried doing it, but this message shows up instead:

C:\Users\ACER\Documents\Tes>for /f %F in ('dir /b /a-d ^| findstr /vile ".png .jpg .mp4"') do del "%F"

C:\Users\ACER\Documents\Tes>del "CACP"
Could Not Find C:\Users\ACER\Documents\Tes\CACP

C:\Users\ACER\Documents\Tes>del "EJAAN"
Could Not Find C:\Users\ACER\Documents\Tes\EJAAN

C:\Users\ACER\Documents\Tes>del "Project"
Could Not Find C:\Users\ACER\Documents\Tes\Project